# How to create a 3rd list from a nested list based on items in another list

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement, nested-lists

I have a list of some users

```
list_of_users=['@elonmusk', '@YouTube','@FortniteGame','@BillGates','@JeffBezos']
```

and a nested list made by tweets, split by words.

```
tweets_splitted_by_words=[['@MrBeastYT', '@BillGates', 'YOU’RE', 'THE', 'LAST', 'ONE', 'FINISH', 'THE', 'MISSION', '#TeamTrees'], ['@MrBeastYT', '@realDonaldTrump', 'do', 'something', 'useful', 'with', 'your', 'life', 'and', 'donate', 'to', '#TeamTrees'], ['Please', 'please', 'donate']]
```

I want to create a third new list made by subblists of tweets_splitted_by_words only if each subblist contains at least one of the users in list_of_users.
Output that I want:

```
output=[['@MrBeastYT', '@BillGates', 'YOU’RE', 'THE', 'LAST', 'ONE', 'FINISH', 'THE', 'MISSION', '#TeamTrees']]
```

I tried the following code but it didn't work out:

```
tweets_per_user_mentioned= []
giorgia=[]
for r in range(len(tweets_splitted_by_words)):
    giorgia.append(r)
    for _i in range(len(giorgia)):
        if _i  in range(len(list_of_users)):
         tweets_per_user_mentioned.append(tweets_splitted_by_words[r])
        else:
            pass
print(tweets_per_user_mentioned)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you will be performing lookups on the list of users, it is a good idea to have a `set` data structure. [Sets provide `O(1)` lookup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)) which greatly reduces time complexity of many problems.

For filtering, I'd just use python's built-in [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and a list comprehension

```
set_of_users = set(list_of_users)
filtered_tweets = [tweet for tweet in tweets_splitted_by_words \
                         if any(word in set_of_users for word in tweet)]
```